# Google Client API connection error on some servers

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, google-client

I'm using the latest version of the Google Client PHP for the purpose of fetching data from YouTube.

I created a server API key from the Google Developer console (in both old and new), enabled the Youtube API and whitelisted my personal IP to allow access to the API. This works without any problems!

Weird thing is, that i keep getting this error when i run the code on my (online) server:

```
                [domain] => usageLimits
                [reason] => accessNotConfigured
                [message] => Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.
                [extendedHelp] => https://console.developers.google.com
```

I tried to run the code on different online servers, while whitelisting it's IP but it keeps giving me this error. When i try to run the code from my own computer with a different IP (home, work, neighbor) it also gives me the same error, but after i whitelist the current IP the error disappears. So whitelisting seems to solve the problem, but only on my local machine and not on any online server.

I already tried to generate new API keys without any luck. I also tried to append the userIp parameter, as provided in the Console documentation. Still no luck.

I'm out of ideas. Does someone know what probably could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I already solved my own question by clearing the allowed IPs field in Google Developer console.

By keeping this field empty it allowes any IP. Discovered this by excident.

I still don't know how it can be that even though im 100% sure i use the correct IP addresses it gave me this error.